# NavigationBar.titleTextAttributes are nil

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, segue

I have 2 view controllers. Now I want to make a present-segue from one to the other. I made the segue in the storyboard, but performed it in the source code of the first vc. The view which will be shown has this line in the viewDidLoad method:

`var font = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes![NSAttributedString.Key.font] as! UIFont`

When the view loads in the segue there is an exception and I checked that the titleTextAttributes are `nil`. When I use the show-segue it works, but I don't want this back-button in my navigation bar.

What is my mistake or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, when you use **present**, you are simply presenting a `ViewControllerB` Over a `ViewControllerA`(Embedded in **NavigationController**), But as `ViewControllerB` is having different NavigationController or may not have Navigation Controller, when you present, so you are getting `nil` there

You can simply remove that line of code and use [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/1619041-init)

```
var font = UIFont(name: "Your Font name", size: YOUR_FONT_SIZE)
```

And do present as your are doing with Segue.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! But now the navigation bar isn't shown. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: Embed your ViewControllerB into NavigationController and Present that

Comment: I tried that and had another problem, but now I'll just use the show-segue and use navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true. Seems to be the easiest solution